# goaddy mail how to use mailgun and office 365 together

Tags: email, dns, mailgun, cname

I've set up mailgun for my domain on godassy via dns to send mails for tech purposes such as verifying emails, resetting passwords etc. , but now I want to use my domain as my business email account myname@mydomain.com and send and receive  emails, I've bought office 365 plan on goaddy but they warn me that I can only use one email service :

[image]

so I assume they will change my dns record ? `CNAME | email | mailgun.org`   ?
If so than I can't use office 365 coz it will disable my mailgun ? what should I do? I can see only one solution is to make mailgun my mail service but is there any info how to accomplish that ? Please help ;(

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I got it wrong , I can use both , but I only can use one for receiving emails

source : https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203357040-Can-I-use-the-same-domain-name-for-Mailgun-and-for-Google-Apps-or-another-email-server-